# AWS SES and sendmail (multiple domains)

Tags: amazon-web-services, sendmail, amazon-ses

guys!

I'm trying to setup my server to send emails through Amazon SES but i'm stuck at this point:

*Add the following lines to the /etc/mail/sendmail.mc file before any MAILER() definitions.*

```
define(`SMART_HOST', `email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com')dnl
define(`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 25')dnl
define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
FEATURE(`authinfo', `hash -o /etc/mail/authinfo.db')dnl
MASQUERADE_AS(`example.com')dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_entire_domain)dnl
```

What if I have, for example, 10 verified domains (example1.com, example2.com etc.)? How config file for sendmail will look like?

Thanks in advance!